# How can I invoke a local HTMl file in a browser using PlatformRequest() in J2me?

Tags: html, browser, java-me

What is the format for such an invocation?For eg if I have file `Test.html` in the same directory as the applicaion and using `platformRequest`, how do I invoke this file in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

The correct function would be [`platformRequest(file:///path/to/Test.html)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29);

BUT, and this is a big but, platformRequest by standard only has to support http:// (for .jad/.jar retrieval) and tel: strings. So, if you try and open a local file, it all depends on the device and if the manufacturer supports this string (file:) for platformRequest

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following example:

```
platformRequest("http://www.cocacola.com");
```